# Time difference from two POSIXct objects is not calculated correctly

Tags: r, datetime, debugging, dst

I have two datetime objects of class POSIXct as follows:

```
> x = as.POSIXct('2013-03-31 01:39:42')
> y = as.POSIXct('2013-03-31 03:11:24')
```

The time difference of the two datetimes is calculated as 31.7 minutes (or 1902 seconds).

```
> y - x
Time difference of 31.7 mins
```

However, the time difference in this case is 91.7 minutes (or 5502 seconds). Can someone please explain to me this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you ever heard of daylight saving time?

```
x
#[1] "2013-03-31 01:39:42 CET"
y
#[1] "2013-03-31 03:11:24 CEST"
```

Look at the time zones.

Compare with this:

```
x = as.POSIXct('2013-03-31 01:39:42', tz="GMT")
y = as.POSIXct('2013-03-31 03:11:24', tz="GMT")
y-x
#Time difference of 1.528333 hours
```

Comment: Nice catch. This must be on *nix systems, on Windows they both report as "CDT"

Comment: @RitchMelton No, this depends on your system's time zone.

Comment: I get that TZ is locale dependent, but how would I change my locale to get it to show the DST value (on Windows)?

Comment: @RitchMelton You might want to read `?timezones`. Also, I don't know when the switch was in the US.